# Pandas: filter rows with loc on anonymous dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I try to create a query such as

```
traffic.groupby([round(traffic.a),traffic.r])[["sn","sbr"]].nunique().loc[a==2,:]
```

The last loc statement does not work (`a==2`): *"name 'a' is not defined*.

How can I filter for rows on such an anonymous dataframe?

** Update **

Here is an example

```
a=[1,2,2,3]
r=[2,2,3,5]
sn=[1,1,2,2]
sbr=[2,2,2,3]

traffic=pd.DataFrame([a,r,sn,sbr],columns=["a","r","sn","sbr"])
traffic.groupby([round(traffic.a),traffic.r])[["sn","sbr"]].nunique().loc[a==2,:]
```

traffic looks like the following:

```
    a   r   sn  sbr
0   1   2   2   3
1   2   2   3   5
2   1   1   2   2
3   2   2   2   3
```

Comment: Add output dataframe. It would made the problem easy to understand

Comment: i added an example

Comment: you just added the input dataframe. Can you add how the output looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [1,2,2,3]
r = [2,2,3,5]
sn = [1,1,2,2]
sbr = [2,2,2,3]

traffic = pd.DataFrame([a,r,sn,sbr],columns=["a","r","sn","sbr"])
traffic.groupby([round(traffic.a),traffic.r])[["sn","sbr"]].nunique().T[2].T
```

The output is:

```
    sn  sbr
r       
2   2   2
```

Comment: Is there a solution without temporarily storing the df?

Comment: I am not sure. I just tried to do it without the temporary variable. But, it got too messy.

Comment: I have modified the code to allow for a temporary variable. Does this solve the problem? @user3579222

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could see your dataframe structure! But the way that I  usually query a row without a name (I assume when you're saying "anonymous", your dataset doesn't have headers) is to use `iloc`.

For example if I want to return the first two rows I would say:

```
dataframe.iloc[[0, 1]]
```

Or if I need to return the first two rows for a specific columns let's say column number 4

```
dataframe.iloc[[0, 1], 3]
```

I hope this would help!

Comment: I added an example. Thank you for your response. But I am looking for an approach using names instead of indexes, and I want to filter with a condition!

Comment: if you don't want to store your df into a temporary df, then you could chain the functions together like this: ```traffic.groupby([round(traffic.a),traffic.r])[["sn","sbr"]].nunique().reset_index().loc[new_df["a"]==2,:]```